# cant install lirc due to higher python version

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lirc

Okay so i got i PiFace2 and i am trying to install pifacecad but you need pyton3lirc but this is what i am trying

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python3-lirc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-lirc : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.3-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```